# Has anyone managed to use older Textmate bundles with Textmate2?

Tags: migration, textmate, textmate2

I specifically want to be able to use Ackmate bundle, peepcode (the new 'Go to file' seems good enough)  and some other custom bundles with TM2.

I tried moving the existing bundles to a location
`~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Managed`
which seem to contain all the new installed bundles, and a few other hack. But no luck yet.

I did manage to get the older themes working with TM2 though, with an approach similar to the one above.

EDIT:

I found this [article](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/locating-bundles/) on the topic.But still not able to get some older bundles to work.
http://blog.macromates.com/2011/locating-bundles/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just copy all your bundles from `~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles` to `~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/`

Answer (score 1):

I did not find much success with the above. I guess its stil in 'Alpha'. Although you might try to drop some of the older bundles into 
`~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Pristine Copy/Bundles` 
to get it working with some hacks for now.I have managed to get *Cucumber*, *[Uber Glory](https://github.com/glennr/uber-glory-tmbundle)* and some of my custom bundles working.

Also you can follow the README of this [Whitespace bundle](http://mads379.github.com/posts/whitespace-tmbundle) to figure out which directory to place your new bundles in. This seems to be only bundle (not packaged) exculsively for TM2 so far.

Answer (score 1):

The Textmate url that explains the difference between 
Avian/Pristine Copy/Bundles/
and 
Avian/Bundles/
is here:
http://blog.macromates.com/2011/locating-bundles/

It didn't recognize my old bundles at first, but the second restart of the app worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is alpha software, I think that the [mailing list](http://lists.macromates.com/listinfo/textmate) is the best venue for your question. Either way, I haven't yet seen anything definitive on the backward compatibility of bundle support.