# Error running osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'

Tags: bash, cucumber, textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I'm trying to install Cucumber bundle for TextMate2. I followed the following instructions from the official page https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-tmbundle:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles
git clone git://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-tmbundle.git Cucumber.tmbundle
osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'
```

After running line 4: osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles', I receive the following error:

```
23:37: syntax error: A identifier can’t go after this identifier. (-2740)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried the steps you listed out and it worked fine, though I have `textmate v1.5`. So the steps works. Can you please check the application name. Is it still `TextMate`? or maybe `TextMate2`?

Comment: it is still TextMate, good point though

Comment: I have this exact same error on Textmate 2, with a totally different package (pep8)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you double-click on the *.tmbundle file, TextMate will ask whether you want to install the Bundle. You no longer have to copy the file into the Library directory.

Comment: To those who downloaded the bundle from Github, simply rename your entire unzipped folder to <bundle>.tmbundle. Then double click like Ken suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but I found that manually nuking everything in ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Cache and restarting TextMate forces all the bundles to reload. Yuck.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot execute that shell command when TextMate is running. Make sure you quit TextMate before trying to execute: osascript -e 'tell app "TextMate" to reload bundles'

I then have a problem installing the cake gem, but that's another question!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Textmate2 for a while now, and I dont think the reload bundles work with it anymore or is even required (I am not sure about this).

It seems like I am not answering your question, but if you intend to have a quick way to get your bundle changes or installations applied, you can just use this, "Hot Quit" option.

http://cl.ly/3D3U3k1z3T121L3u0V1s

Anyway with TM2 now saving sessions, all you need to do it just restart textmate and will not lose any context. And as usual I dont think you can complain above TM taking anytime at all to load.

On a different note, I havent been able to get the Cucumber bundle to work with TM2 in spite of several hack and attempts. Did you have any luck with that?

EDIT:
I have been since then able to get the bundle to work for me after some minor changes to it. You could try it in the fork of the bundle here. Also author of the bundle might have made the same fix in the original version as well.

github.com/anandhak/cucumber-tmbundle

Comment: I'm still trying but with no luck... what's strange to me is that I'm cloning the Cucumber bundle into ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles where I don't have any bundles. Where are the other bundles installed?

Comment: Textmate2 expects all the new bundles under ~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles. Take a look at some suggestions under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531265/has-anyone-managed-to-use-older-textmate-bundles-with-textmate2.

Comment: I have realized most of the old bundle dont 'just' work even if you move them to the correct location. I have managed to hack a bit to get jslint to work. [Look here](https://github.com/anandhak/jslintmate). (The original author has a cleaner fix, but I just want to point out that you get stuff working by fixing the paths). Also I think the Avian directory is probably only while TM2 is still alpha. Do let me know if get cucumber to work. Will be of great help to me. Thanks.

Comment: @jake Thanks!  That worked like a champ!  It might be helpful if you edit your answer to include the fork that you added in the comments, as it worked no problem for me.